# Are Questions on SyFy channel series valuable?

Tags: discussion

As well as being a fan of traditional written si-fi, I also love some of the series on the SiFi channel - Lost Girl, Eureka, Warehouse 13.

My question is not so much whether these are on-topic, as I presume that they are. the question is more whether they are valuable on this site, in terms of whether there are enough other people who watch and enjoy these. Would this aspect make a valuable addition, or would I end up talking to myself ( as so often )?

Comment: Anything that has to do with Science Fiction and fantasy as outlined in the FAQs is ABSOLUTELY valuable to the site.

Comment: What channel a show is on is as immaterial as who published a book.  I doubt most people outside of the US know or care whether a show was screened on SyFy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SyFy channel series are definitely on-topic and welcome here:

- [stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate): 247 questions
- [battlestar-galactica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica): 133 questions
- [caprica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caprica): 8 questions
- [eureka](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eureka): 11 questions
- [warehouse-13](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warehouse-13): 13 questions
- [lost-girl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-girl): 5 questions

We also have a pretty big tradition with other “pop” SciFi shows, past and present:

- [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek): 2911 questions
- [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who): 1106 questions
- [firefly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefly): 80 questions
- [terminator](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator): 157 questions
- [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama) (!): 205 questions
- [transformers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformers): 113 questions
- [heroes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes): 22 questions

In reality, whether a question is valuable has less to do with what canon or series they come from and more to do with how unlikely they are easily answered by a general source (like Wikipedia or the appropriate Wikia) and definitively answerable they are in general (i.e. “Explain X to me” instead of “What’s your favorite X in series Y?”).

I, for one, would like to see more interesting *Eureka* questions: ask away!

Comment: Cool - I had looked and not found the Eureka or W13 questions. Which made me wonder whether I was the only person to watch these.

Answer (score 3):

Any questions is appropriate, even if the user base is really small. I've asked questions on other sites that the total pool of users was only in the hundreds if not less, but it was on topic, and actually got an answer.